# @RequestMapping(params={"myyParam"}) seems to be getting ignored?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, parameters, request-mapping

I am redirecting to page using basic javascript:

```
window.location = "handleMyPage.ctl?myNewParameter=1234";
```

however when the flow of control (correctly) gets to my controller, the request is instead handled by a different (incorrect) function.

My function is annotated like:

```
    @RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST }, params={"somePreExisingParameterIAmNotUsing"})

    protected ModelAndView otherHandler(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        log.info("This gets called for some reason!"); 
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST }, params={"myNewParameter"})
    protected ModelAndView handlerIActuallyWantCalled(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        log.info("this never gets called?"); 
    }
```

I have inspected the request at the server side - and I can see the parameterMap contains only "myNewParameter" and no trace of "somePreExisingParameterIAmNotUsing" - yet still the function which references somePreExisingParameterIAmNotUsing is the only one that ever gets called.

it's worth noting, somePreExisingParameterIAmNotUsing is also the first function referenced - so I believe the request dispatcher may just be defaulting to the first function...

I know window.location= will only ever trigger GET HTTP verbs - but I'm fine with that for now - surely the method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST } should cover that?

Does param not work in requestMapping when it's a GET request?

Answer (score 0):

Identified the issue as I was about to hit submit.

My controller turned out to be very old: it was extending AbstractController - which is an implementation of the template method design pattern.

So Spring was looking for specific function names it expected to be implemented, and not using my annotations.

So since at some point in the code's history, someone came along and added annotations, without removing the old inherited request mapping approach - not realizing because there was only one controller function that the annotations did nothing.

Removing the `extends AbstractController` reference, and ensuring my controller was configured for annotations was the solution.